# The marginal propensity to consume and the multiplier according to Keynes

Tags: classical-economics, keynes, multiplier

In "The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money", Chapter 10: [The marginal propensity to consume and the multiplier](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0300071h/chap10.html), John Maynard Keynes says:

> Our normal psychological law that, when the real income of the community increases or decreases, its consumption will increase or decrease but not so fast, can, therefore, be translated¾not, indeed, with absolute accuracy but subject to qualifications which are obvious and can easily be stated in a formally complete fashion into the propositions that $\Delta C_w$ and $\Delta Y_w$ have the same sign, but $\Delta Y_w >\Delta C_w $, where $C_w$ is the consumption in terms of wage-units. This is merely a repetition of the proposition already established in Chapter 3 above. Let us define, then, $dC_w/dY_w$ as the *marginal propensity to consume*.
>
> This quantity is of considerable importance, because it tells us how the next increment of output will have to be divided between consumption and investment. For $\Delta Y_w  =  \Delta C_w + \Delta I_w$, where $C_w$ and $I_w$ are the increments of consumption and investment; so that we can write $\Delta Y_w   =  k\Delta I_w$, where $1-1/k$ is equal to the marginal propensity to consume.
>
> Let us call $k$ the *investment multiplier*. It tells us that, when there is an increment of aggregate investment, income will increase by an amount which is k times the increment of investment.

I don't understood how Keynes make this step: "For $\Delta Y_w  =  \Delta C_w + \Delta I_w$, where $C_w$ and $I_w$ are the increments of consumption and investment; so that we can write $\Delta Y_w   =  k\Delta I_w$, where $1-1/k$ is equal to the marginal propensity to consume."

How is "$\Delta Y_w  = k\Delta I_w$" inferred from "$\Delta Y_w  =  \Delta C_w + \Delta I_w$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$\Delta Y_w= \Delta C_w+ \Delta I_w$$

we have

$$1=\frac{\Delta C_w}{\Delta Y_w}+\frac{\Delta I_w}{\Delta Y_w}$$

or

$$\frac{\Delta I_w}{\Delta Y_w}=1-\frac{\Delta C_w}{\Delta Y_w}$$

Setting $1-1/k=\frac{\Delta C_w}{\Delta Y_w}$ (the marginal propensity to consume), we have

$$\frac{\Delta I_w}{\Delta Y_w}=\frac{1}{k}$$

so that

$$\Delta Y_w=k\Delta I_w.$$

---

Alternatively, substituting $\Delta C_w=(1-1/k)\Delta Y_w$ into

$$\Delta Y_w= \Delta C_w+ \Delta I_w$$

gives:

$$\Delta Y_w= \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\Delta Y_w +\Delta I_w$$

or

$$0= -\frac{1}{k}\Delta Y_w +\Delta I_w$$

so that

$$\Delta Y_w=k\Delta I_w.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your notation isn't the cleanest, and my notation is a little shaky, but here is the idea. It's just algebra resulting from plugging $$\partial C_W / \partial Y_W = 1-1/k \implies \mathbf{D} C_W = (1-1/k) \mathbf{D}Y_W$$ into the identity $$\mathbf{D}Y_W = \mathbf{D} C_W+\mathbf{D} I_W.$$
After simplifying, you will see that the two equations are equivalent.